# How to close a tkinter dialog box after running another function?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am working with python `tkinter` and I have a dialog box window that pops up. I have two buttons in the box:

```
from tksheet import Sheet
from tkinter import *
import os 
import sys
import mapMaker2


root=Tk()
root.title('Map Tool')
root.geometry("750x750")


sheetframe = Frame(root)
sheetframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0,)


buttonEditlabel = Button(sheetframe, text='Edit Labels', width=12, command=lambda: [openEditWindow()], bg='#cacccf',fg='black')
buttonEditlabel.grid(row = 0, sticky=W, column = 0, pady = (25,5), padx = (50,0))


def openEditWindow():

    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.geometry("260x195")
    top.title('Edit Axes Labels')
    frm = Frame(top, borderwidth=0, relief='ridge')
    frm.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = (20,0),padx=(20,0))


    b_cancel = Button(frm, text='Close', width=10)
    b_cancel['command'] = top.destroy
    b_cancel.grid(column = 0, row = 6, pady = (15,0),padx=(0,0))

    b_save = Button(frm, text='Save', width=10)
    b_save['command'] = lambda: editLabels()
    b_save.grid(column = 1, row = 6, sticky = E, pady = (15,0),padx=(0,0))


    def editLabels():
        pass


mainloop()
```

<kbd>Cancel</kbd> button closes the window with `top.destroy` command. I would like the <kbd>Save</kbd> button to also close the window after running the `editLabels()` function first. I have tried:

```
b_save['command'] = [lambda: editLabels(), top.destroy]
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you supply a more complete [mre] (MRE) that at least includes the construction of the dialog box?

Comment: Just write a function and pass the function name.  `b_save['command'] = editLabels`.  Now you can have `editLabels` call `top.destroy()`.

Comment: I added a MRE, and adding top.destroy to editLabels function didnt work for me, it doesn't execute top.destroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it. Create a function to destroy the top window.

```
def kill_main():
    top.destroy()
    top.update()
```

Then call the function wherever you want. You don't have to add kill_main() to the button itself. Just put it inside the next function you are opening so that it will close the Top windows first and then run the rest of the editlabels() function. Hopefully, it makes sense to you.

```
def editLabels():
    kill_main()
    pass
```